# meteor S3 file upload not working at server code i am using cfs:s3

Tags: javascript, meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-collections

I have added three package

```
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:filesystem
cfs:s3
```

error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
```

s3.js

```
var avatarStoreLarge = new FS.Store.S3("temp", {
    region: "eu-west-1", //optional in most cases
    accessKeyId: "XXX", //required if environment variables are not set
    secretAccessKey: "XX", //required if environment variables are not set
    bucket: "temp", //required
    ACL:'public-read-write'
});
var filestore = new FS.Collection("temp", {
    stores: [avatarStoreLarge]
});
```

client.js

```
var avatarStoreLarge = new FS.Store.S3("temp")
var filestore = new FS.Collection("temp", {
    stores: [avatarStoreLarge]
})
filestore.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    },
    download: function(){
        return true;
    }
});
filestore.deny({
 insert: function(){
   return false;
 },
 update: function(){
   return false;
 },
 remove: function(){
   return false;
 },
 download: function(){
   return false;
}    
 });
```

server js

```
        var fsFile = new FS.File(fileContent);
        fsFile.metadata = {owner: Meteor.user()._id};
        filestore.insert(fsFile});
```

this keep give me error for upload 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

but if i move server code to client.js it do upload file on S3.
what's problem with Upload on S3 from server code.

can You please help me to resolve this error.
how we can get out of this error what's wrong with my code or config.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it is a syntax error?

You are missing `"` at the end of this line: `bucket: "temp, //required`

Comment: thanks but this is not the case in my program its properly with "" and i able to upload file from inside client code but not able to from server code

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to upload the files through the server? According to the CollectionFS docs, inserting files via the client is the preferred method, unless the files are already in your filesystem to begin with. [link] (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#using-insert-properly).

Answer (score 0):

Hi try putting your permission "allow" rule on the server side
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#storage-adapters

```js
filestore.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    },
    download: function(){
        return true;
    }
});
```